# I am trying to make a basic Grocery Store without prices

Tags: python

```
class Toptanci:
def __init__(self):
    self.fruits = dict(apple=30, pear=40, cherry=20, banana=10, strawberry=15)

    self.vegetables = dict(garlic=40, Tomatoes=30, Eggplant=40, Onion=25, Potato=15)

    self.all_list = self.fruits and self.vegetables ## YANLIS OLABILIR !

def report(self):  ### RAPOR
    print(self.fruits and self.vegetables)

def is_resource_sufficient(self, purchase):  ### YETERLI VAR MI DIYE BAK
    can_purchase = True
    for item in purchase.all_list:
        if purchase.all_list[item] > self.all_list[item]:
            print(f"Sorry there is not enough {item}")
            can_purchase = False
    return can_purchase

def order_purchase(self, order): ### GEREKLI AMOUNUT"U CIKAR
    for item in order.all_list:
        self.all_list[item] -= order.all_list[item]
    print(f"Here is your {order}")


def main(self):
    question1 = input("Fruits or Vegetables?").lower()
    question2 = int(input("Please enter the KG amount you want ="))
    question3 = input("Would you like something else? 'y' or 'n'").lower()

    if question1 == 'fruits':
        print(question2)
```

Basically, I am trying to get input from the user and deduct the amount from the base values. In addition, I want to add the amount I get from the Toptanci class into the Manav class. So when in Manav section the amount gathered will be added. In the Manav Class we should have the amount of vegetable or fruits bought and it should display the bought amount. So when another user tries to buy from Manav. It will see Manav's stock and the stock will be reduced accordingly.

Comment: self.all_list felt so wrong. It may not be, but it felt like that.

Comment: What is your question? You've described your program but I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: @JohnKugelman My question is that how can I get to do the question2 part in def main(self)... So I can't implement the order_purchase method into my main(self) method.